# Python Timeseries Pandas: remove np.nan if more than 3 occurrences continuously

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries dataframe with column [timestamp,Digital_Data]

Could you guide me how to remove all rows that are matches if the digital_Data consecutively np.nan for more than three occurrence. data sample as below.

Sorry i am not sure how to add a table here, it turns into image when i copy and paste it from excel

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIVJY.png)

Answer (score 0):

There MUST be a pythonic way to solve it, or even a solution provided by pandas itself, and I encourage you to search! but just in case you urgently need the solution, here is how I solve it:

### 1. example

```
x = [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

output is

```
      x   y
0   1.0   1
1   2.0   2
2   NaN   3
3   NaN   4
4   NaN   5
5   NaN   6
6   2.0   7
7   1.0   8
8   NaN   9
9   NaN  10
10  3.0  11
```

### 2. Get NaN indices

```
ind = df[df.x.isna()].index.tolist()
```

### 3. Get the block of adjacent NaN indices

I create an empty holder `inds_to_delete` and fill it with the blocks of adjacent indices. I check the adjacency by checking if the element `i` is 1 more than `i-1`

```
# first element by default in temp
temp = [ind[0]]
for i in range(1, len(ind)):
    try:
        assert ind[i] == ind[i-1] + 1
        # if condition holds, append to temp
        temp.append(ind[i])
    except AssertionError:
        # if condition doesn't hold, we have a break, append temp to holder
        inds_to_delete.append(temp)
        # restart temp for the next block
        temp = [ind[i]]
# last block of the series also appended to the holder
inds_to_delete.append(temp)
```

output of `inds_to_delete`

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

### 4. blocks with length more than 2 and joining

```
inds_to_delete = [i for i in inds_to_delete if len(i)>2]
>>> [[2, 3, 4, 5]]
inds_to_delete = [i for j in inds_to_delete for i in j]
>>> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if `inds_to_delete` is `[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]]` then final line makes it: `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]`

### 5. Drop from dataframe

```
df.drop(inds_to_delete, inplace=True)
```

output is

```
    x       y
0   1.0     1
1   2.0     2
6   2.0     7
7   1.0     8
8   NaN     9
9   NaN     10
10  3.0     11
```

(maybe this solution can be awarded by SO as the most unpythonic solution)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alireza, and as you said i hope there will be a pythonic way to solve this.

I have temporarily fixed it with the below code assuming the threshold is more than 15 for nan removal:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)),  columns =['TimeStamp','FHR']).set_index('TimeStamp', drop=True)
df = df = df.resample('S').mean()
TimeStampToRemove = []
fhrtoremove = []
df1 = df
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    fhr = df['FHR'][i]

    if  np.isnan(fhr):

        TimeStampToRemove.append(df.index[i])
        fhrtoremove.append(fhr)

    else:
        if len(TimeStampToRemove) > 15:

            df1toRemove = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(TimeStampToRemove,fhrtoremove)),  columns =['TimeStamp','FHR']).set_index('TimeStamp', drop=True)


            TimeStampToRemove.clear()
            fhrtoremove.clear()
            df1 = df1.drop(df1toRemove.index.tolist())    


if len(TimeStampToRemove) > 0:
    df1toRemove = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(TimeStampToRemove,fhrtoremove)),  columns =['TimeStamp','FHR']).set_index('TimeStamp', drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1toRemove.index.tolist()) 
    TimeStampToRemove.clear()
    fhrtoremove.clear()
```